# Infinite recursion when serializing objects with Jackson and Mockito

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, mockito

I ran into this issue when testing a Spring controller using MockMvc, Mockito and Jackson, so I made a simple class to test out how Jackson behaves. I'm using jackson-databind:2.3.1 and mockito-core:1.9.5.

Given this class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.Serializable;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class Person implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    // Public getters and setters...

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = "Bob";
        int age = 21;
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // attempt serialization with real object
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName(name);
        person.setAge(age);
        try {
            System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(person));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Failed to serialize real object");
        }

        // attempt serialization with mock object
        Person mockPerson = mock(Person.class);
        when(mockPerson.getName()).thenReturn(name);
        when(mockPerson.getAge()).thenReturn(age);
        try {
            System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(mockPerson));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Failed to serialize mock object.");
        }
    }
```

Jackson has no problem serializing the real object, however it will throw a JsonMappingException when it tries to serialize the mocked object. Debugging through the code, it's calling serializeFields(bean, jgen, provider) repeatedly, getting stuck on the internal Mockito properties.

So, my question is: Is there anyway to force Jackson to use the getter methods? I tried @JsonIgnoreProperties on the class, @JsonIgnore on the fields, and @JsonProperty on the methods (in different combinations, to no success). Or, do I have to write my own custom serializer?

Thanks!

Comment: They're in the code! I just excluded them for readability - they just simply return the value of the private field in this example.

Comment: jackson will use the getter method but those need to be adhering to the naming conventions

Comment: I assure you, the getters / setters follow Java naming conventions. I've even added @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true) to the class, and the StackOverflowError exception still occurs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a solution that will work for you particular case:

First of all you need to create a PersonMixin since you cannot add the required annotations to the mock.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;


@JsonAutoDetect(getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, isGetterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
public interface PersonMixin {

    @JsonProperty
    String getName();

    @JsonProperty
    Integer getAge();
}
```

Now, use the object mapper like the in following code and you will get the same result as when you serialize the real object:

```
Person mockPerson = mock(Person.class);
when(mockPerson.getName()).thenReturn(name);
when(mockPerson.getAge()).thenReturn(age);
objectMapper.addMixInAnnotations(Person.class, PersonMixin.class);
try {
    System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(mockPerson));
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.err.println("Failed to serialize mock object.");
}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Is this strictly a Mockito limitation? I didn't come across anything in their documentation regarding mocks retaining the annotations of their classes.

Comment: @MatthewSerrano Your welcome! Actually your right, you do not need the mixin! If you put the annotations on Person it will work for the mock object as well! I didn't even think of that because I took for granted that mockito would not retain the annotations, when in fact it does!
However I would still stick with the annotations on the mixin, because the annotations are only needed for the mock, and therefor introducing them into the business object would introduce complexity that is only needed for the purpose of mocking

Comment: @SalihKardan Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 5):

Here's my `ObjectMapper` that sorted it out without the need for mixins.

The mapper ignores all members of that has "Mockito" in somewhere in their names.

This solution avoids having a mix-in for each serialized object, or annotating code that may not be accessible.

Running the following test succeeds with the output `{"name":"Jonh"}`.

```
package test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMember;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

public class AppTest extends Mockito {

    public void testApp() throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector() {

            @Override
            public boolean hasIgnoreMarker(final AnnotatedMember m) {
                return super.hasIgnoreMarker(m) || m.getName().contains("Mockito");
            }
        });

        final String name = "Jonh";

        Person mockPerson = mock(Person.class);
        when(mockPerson.getName()).thenReturn(name);
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(mockPerson));
    }


    public static class Person {

        private String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Minor improvement here: instead of setting introspector you should add one: mapper.getSerializationConfig().withAppendedAnnotationIntrospector(new SkipMockitoAnnotationIntrospector()). In the other case other annotations will not be processed by jackson.